# using a compareTo when want to compare on two variables

Tags: java, string, getter-setter, schedule, compareto

I am writing a program that has 3 classes. The program is to read in a file that lists appointments you have and reads them into schedule[].  Once you read them into the schedule you need to sort them. You also have to be able to add additional appointments and also be able to search for an appointment.  The first line of the input file looks like this:

11/10/2013 14:00 Discuss student programming logic

where 11/10/2013 is a string called date, 14:00 is a string called time, the remaining sentence is a string called text.  I have read these all into my array schedule as string, string, string

My teacher created a compareTo statement in the Appointment class that joins date and time because the search and sort needs to be done on these two combined, and we have never done a compareTo that had two variables.

Here is the compareTo in Appointment () like this:

```
public int compareTo(Appointment other)
{
    String one, two;
    one = this.date + this.time;
    two = other.date + other.time;
    return one.compareTo(two);
} // end compareTo
```

In the Schedule class, I have to call a class "find", ask user to input a date and time, then call a binary search() of my schedule to see if there is a match and that I have an appointment that date and time and then back in find(),output either no apt or the details of the appt.   I have done this before, but when I was searching only one thing, such as date...  My code is written to search on date because I just couldn't figure out how to make it use that compareTo and search on the two together (date+time)and I had to turn in something... now I just want to know what was the right way!!.  I have tried putting "one" and "two" in place of date, various different things... but so frustrated. Nothing works.  Can someone please show me how this should be written in the search.  I am having two problems:  1. I am only searching on date as opposed to date+time.  2. in my compareTo in the binary search I get error saying "the method compareTo string in the type string is not applicable for arguments Appointment."

Here is my find method that calls my binary search method:

```
private void find()
{
    String inDate, inTime;
    int position;
    Appointment searchArg = new Appointment();

    // get info from user

    System.out.println ("Enter Date and Time separated by space: ");
    inDate = console.next();
    inTime = console.next();

    position = binarySearch(schedule, numAppointments, searchArg);
    //should that last thing be "searchArg"? or "date"? or what??
    if (position == -1)
        System.out.println(" appointment does not exist");
    else
        System.out.println("\nAppointment =");
    outputOneAppointment(position+1);       
}

private int binarySearch(Appointment[] list, int listLength, Appointment searchItem)
{
    int first = 0;
    int last = listLength - 1;
    int mid = 0;

    boolean found = false;

    while (first <= last && !found)
    {
        mid = (first + last) / 2;

        if (list[mid].date.equals(searchItem))
            found = true;  //I should not search date but rather the date and time together
        else if (list[mid].date.compareTo(searchItem) > 0)  
            //I also get that error here saying what I wrote above in my question                                   
            last = mid - 1;
        else
            first = mid + 1;
    }
    if (!found)
        mid = -1; //it is an unsuccessful search

    return mid;
}//end binarySearch
```

Comment: "You also have to be able to add additional appointments and also be able to search for an appointment" -> you should probably use an ArrayList or equivalent since arrays are fixed size.

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing a date (of which you provided no info) to an `Appointment`

```
list[mid].date.compareTo(searchItem)
```

instead, you should be comparing objectsof the same type, presumably:

```
list[mid].date.compareTo(searchItem.date)
```

However, this is a bit *hacky*, and should not really be done that way. Instead, [implement a `Comparator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) that compares `Appointment` objects:

```
final class AppointmentDateComparator implements Comparator<Appointment> {

    @Override
    public int compare (Appointment a1, Appointment a2) {
        // Implement your comparison logic here...
    }
}
```

You could also make `Appointment` implement `Comparable`, but it doesn't seem like date comparison is a proper natural ordering.

Also note that Java provides `Arrays.binarySearch` already to perform binary searches.

Comment: thanks. We haven't learned comparable yet and she wanted us to use one of the binary searches we went over at class. I will try the searchItem.date. She didn't use date as the name, she used "one" and "two" in her compareTo that I lested above. I didn't know whether to use searchItem.one??? not sure how that works. I have sone it before where I did just the date when searching only date,  but with the date+time, I was not sure what to do.  Thanks again